# Jquery countdown warn user 5 minutes before time over

Tags: jquery, jquery-countdown

I'm using Jquery countdown in my project (http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/). I want to warn user 5 minutes before the end the counter (displaying an alert) and 10 minutes after the end of the counter . 
In the website documentation i saw that, there is a an event called elapsed giving the information that time is over.

Any suggestions please? My guess is that i have to work with the event call finaldate.

Comment: Did you tried anything with this `elapsed` ? If yes, add it to you question. If no... Well, try something and come back.

Comment: Hi @LouysPatriceBessette it's ok now. i used the offset.minutes event to get the minutes left for the next hour, so that i'm able to know if there is only 5 minutes before  to reach the elapsed event . Thanks

Comment: Your problem is fixed, I suppose... Then post what you've done (detailled plz!) as an answer... OR remove your question (will fix your *bad reputation*... Since you where downvoted for an uncomplete question. ;) )

Comment: Done @LouysPatriceBessette . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. To warn user , i used the offset.minutes event on update callback. Here is the code

```
flag2 = true;

$('#clock').countdown(dateseance, { elapse: true }).on('update.countdown', function (event) {

                if (event.offset.minutes == (4) && flag2) {
                    alert("Less than 5 minutes before the end of counter");
                    flag2 = false;
                }
```

We use flag2 to display alert only once. So when the counter get 4mn 59 s the alert will be displayed.